# Add style attribute to images in divs with PHP

Tags: replace, preg-replace

I have a newsletter that contains a few image inside a div called `nieuwsbrief-tekst`. I want to find those images and add inline css code to it. I can find the div with `preg_match`, and I can also find the image tag itself, but adding the `style=""` to the image tag hasn't worked so far.

There is also more then one `nieuwsbief-tekst` div, these divs are the different content blocks, so there are 3 or 4 of them. I tried the `preg_replace`, but that has no effect.

Any tips or suggestions how to handle this?

So the html would look like this, and I only want add the style attribute to the images inside the div.

HTM Code:

```
<div class="nieuwsbrief-tekst">lorum ipmsum</div>
<div class="nieuwsbrief-tekst"><img src="#"></div>
<div class="nieuwsbrief-tekst">lorum ipmsum</div>
<div class="nieuwsbrief-tekst"><img src="#"></div>
```

PHP Code:

```
if(preg_match_all('/<div class="nieuwsbrief-tekst">(.*?)<\/div>/is', $var, $matches)) {

foreach($matches[0] as $match) {

    if(preg_match('/<img[^>]+>/is', $match, $match_img)) {

        echo 'image found';

        $pattern = '/<img[^>]+>/is';
        $replacement = '<img style="float:left; margin:0 10px 10px 0;';
        $test = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $match_img);

    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print($test);
echo '</pre>';

}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: It's `Lorem Ipsum`, not `Lorem IpMsum` :P

Answer (score 0):

this should accomplish what you want

```
$pattern = "/<div class=\"tmp\">(\\w+)?<img ([^>]+)>(\\w+)?<\/div>/is";
$replacement = "<div class=\"tmp\">\\1 <img style=\"float:left; margin:0 10px 10px 0; \\2 /> \\3</div>";

$str = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
echo $str;
```

Just change the tmp to fit your needs :)

Comment: Almost perfect :) It works if the image and the div are on the same line, but if the image starts on the next line it doesn't work? I did some searching and the /s should take care of that, but it doesn't?

I can't control where the user adds the image in the content, so can't force the image to always start directly on the same line as the div